# Android: DatabaseException.Cannot convert java.lang.string to type our pojo class in Firebase google

Tags: android

Below is the code..Suggest me what wrong i am doing?

```
private void Update(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for(DataSnapshot da: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        EventModel eventModel= new EventModel();

        eventModel.setName(da.getValue(EventModel.class).getName());
        eventModel.setVenue(da.getValue(EventModel.class).getVenue());
        eventModel.setDate(da.getValue(EventModel.class).getDate());
        eventModel.setImageUrl(da.getValue(EventModel.class).getImageUrl());
        events.add(eventModel);
    }
}
```